# What do all of the mode enums mean?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

What do all the various **mode** constants in [blender operators documentation](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.duplicate) do?

> bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=False, mode='**TRANSLATION**') - 
>   Duplicate selected objects
>
> Parameters:
>
> - linked (boolean, (optional)) – Linked, Duplicate object but not object data, linking to the original data
> - mode (enum in [‘INIT’, ‘DUMMY’, ‘TRANSLATION’, ‘ROTATION’, ‘RESIZE’, ‘SKIN_RESIZE’, ‘TOSPHERE’, ‘SHEAR’, ‘BEND’, ‘SHRINKFATTEN’, ‘TILT’, ‘TRACKBALL’, ‘PUSHPULL’, ‘CREASE’, ‘MIRROR’, ‘BONE_SIZE’, ‘BONE_ENVELOPE’, ‘CURVE_SHRINKFATTEN’, ‘MASK_SHRINKFATTEN’, ‘GPENCIL_SHRINKFATTEN’, ‘BONE_ROLL’, ‘TIME_TRANSLATE’, ‘TIME_SLIDE’, ‘TIME_SCALE’, ‘TIME_EXTEND’, ‘BAKE_TIME’, ‘BWEIGHT’, ‘ALIGN’, ‘EDGESLIDE’, ‘SEQSLIDE’], (optional)) – Mode

Comment: Most of these seem self explanatory. I would like to see a list of all of them compiled together though

Comment: @10Replies, self-explanatory for someone with experience for sure, but for a noob like me it's just a source of confusion.

Comment: enum lists all subfunctions of a blender https://vimeo.com/103321600